# merge sort algorithm: std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I am currently making a merge sort algorithm but when i run the code i get an error says "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range". This is my code.

```
template<typename T>
void merge(std::vector<T> &vec, int l, int m, int r){
    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    int k = l;
    
    //CREATE TEMPORARY MEMORY
    int temp[vec.size()];

    while(vec.at(i) <= m && j <= r){
        if(vec.at(i) <= vec.at(j)){
            temp[k] = vec.at(i);
            i++;
            k++;
        }else{
            temp[k] = vec.at(j);
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= m){ //first half: Copy the remaining elements of first half, if there are any
        temp[k] = vec.at(i);
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j <= r){ //second half: Copy the remaining elements of second half, if there are any 
        temp[k] = vec.at(j);
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for(size_t p = 1; p <= r; p++){ //copy temp array to original array
        vec.at(p) = temp[k];
    }
}
```

Merge Sort Function

```
template<typename T>
void mergeSort(std::vector<T> &vec, int l, int r){
    if(l < r){ 
        int m = (l + r) / 2; //find midpoint
        mergeSort(vec, l, m); //first half
        mergeSort(vec, m + 1, r); //second half
        merge(vec, l, m, r); // merge
    }
}
```

Comment: The one thing you can be pretty sure of is that it's _not_ `temp` that you try accessing out of range because that would most probably not result in a soft exception like your `at()` calls will throw. Suggestion: Print the index value and `vec.size()` right before you do `vec.at(index)`

Comment: The next step in debugging would be to determine which line throws the exception, the value of the parameter to `at()` in that line, and the size of `vec` in that line.

Comment: When in doubt, print stuff out.

Comment: `int temp[vec.size()];` -- This is not valid C++.   You are using `std::vector` already, so why didn't you use it here?  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  That line should be `std::vector<int> temp(vec.size());`

Comment: I tried that method but it resulted me the same output and also I don't know how to specify the size of a vector, how can I specify the size of a vector?

Comment: @PioloTorrecampo The point is not that it will fix your issue.  The issue with your current code is that it isn't valid C++.  Variable length arrays are not C++.

Comment: okay, sorry i am currently new using vectors, but the main goal of this code is to implement vector aside of array.

Comment: Regardless of your goal, you need to change that line of code I pointed out.  Otherwise you are not writing C++.

Comment: A great way to solve problems like this is to run in a debugger with "break on exception thrown" enabled.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie whether it's portable C++ or not, if his compiler allows him to do it, then it's probably not the cause of his underlying problem. Even if it's poor practice.

Comment: @PioloTorrecampo *but when i run the code* -- There is nothing to run, since there is no `main` program that utilizes these classes.  What is the test data that you're using?  I

Comment: @JosephLarson -- That's why I made my comments in the comment section and not put that as an answer.  In any respect, the OP should be notified that the code they are running is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues in your `merge` function (which you can spot easily through debugging):

1. `vec.at(i) <= m` compares a *value* with an *index*. These two are unrelated. So change:

   ```
   while(vec.at(i) <= m && j <= r){
   ```

   with:

   ```
   while(i <= m && j <= r){
   ```
2. The final loop starts with `p = 1` which is an index that in many cases is out of the range that is being merged. So change:

   ```
   for(size_t p = 1; p <= r; p++){
   ```

   with:

   ```
   for(size_t p = l; p <= r; p++){
   ```
3. The body of that same loop uses `k` as index, but that variable is unrelated to the loop, and has a value that is out of the range that is under consideration. So change:

   ```
   vec.at(p) = temp[k];
   ```

   with:

   ```
   vec.at(p) = temp[p];
   ```

With those changes your code will work.

However, it is a pity that `temp` always has the size of the complete vector, while you only *use* a subsection of it. Consider reducing the memory usage.